# Google Sheets highlight a column if a checkbox is checked and also matches an input, applied to the whole row

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, conditional-formatting

So I don't know what to call this so that explains my title, but I have a solution that works, except I want to have this apply to a row of checks so I dont have to duplicate my conditional formatting for every column.
This is for a game called Phasmophobia, and I wanted to make a sheet I can select checkboxes to show potential answers for the game.
Here is my example:

[Basic View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJrXw.png)

[Highlighted View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXXvj.png)

My conditional formatting function is =if(($C$3=TRUE)*($C6=$C$2),true,false)
So what I want is to check if the checkbox is TRUE, then highlight rows that has the corresponding data in the row. This formula works as intended, my only issue is I want to make this formula work for all the checkboxes in one formula, so I don't have to make 20 conditional formatting, because on top of the current formula I have plans to modify it to have 2 additional conditions to highlight for, for example if the checkbox below the top row is checked, then cross off instead of highlight the same rows from the first formula, and to cross off rows which don't contain the correct information. If this isn't possible I can just suck it up and make the conditional formatting rules manually, but I know this game has intentions to add more things to track and I wanted a simple "paste in and it works" solution.

P.S. I only have it comparing the ($C6=$C$2) because it makes it possible to remove the need to keep the columns all lined up with the checkboxes, but I can remove that in place of a "istext($c6)" check.

Link to a copy of my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I1be4O6BH4S0HscRsY-1NFPOyVm_8F7zr642Bbu28Qg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Currently, your target sheet has nearly 1000 rows, of which you are using fewer than 20. What will the actual maximum number of rows be for this sheet? I ask because an CF formula implementation to do what you're asking will be fairly complex; and processing will apply to even unused rows, slowing your sheet way down. So keeping the sheet to only the max number of rows you'll be using will be necessary to best performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula for `OR` condition

```
=sumproduct($C$3:$H$3,$C6:$H6=$C$2:$H$2)
```

try this one for `AND` condition

```
=sumproduct($C$3:$H$3,$C6:$H6=$C$2:$H$2)=sumproduct(N($C$3:$H$3))
```

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the user wants to highlight all rows that use checkboxes as OR or as AND. Your formula should produce the OR result; but I suspect the user wants the AND result (to use as process of elimination, like in the game CLUE).

Comment: Your are right. I will try to find a way for `AND` condition

Comment: I have completed my answer

Comment: So both work, the only difference is the AND condition solution will highlight all rows due to everything being "FALSE" while as the OR condition solution will highlight individual rows if the condition I wanted checked is true, so I will go with the OR Solution thank you.

Comment: I made a simple edit for anyone who wants to use this in the future, this edit will allow the check to continue on indefinitely I believe
=sumproduct($C$3:$3,$C6:6=$C$2:$2)